# Using Multiple Times Child Component in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, parent-child

I'm Trying to Learn the Parent-child Communication in Angular 4+

my question is simple :
I have a Button array List `[0, 1, 2, 3]` in the Child component, and I am using child Selector `<app-child>` multiple times in my parent component `my-app`,
so when the user clicks on any button on the first child tag, List is updating to `[5, 6, 7, 8]`
and it does not update the second tag.
2nd child tag also needs to be updated when the user click on 1st tag

is there any way to also update the same time both when we are using the child component multiple times

you can see here demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dswut1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: If you want to share data among components, you need a singleton. Services are singletons. Store the data once in a service, then inject the service in all your components. Then, in the component, display `{{myService.variableName}}`.

Comment: thankyou for your answer. but i have an requirement, i am using same child component multiple times in an page. it is working fine in first time but at 2nd time the data is not rendering

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inputs and outputs. If you want to handle the child components data this is the best way to send input from wrapper and take output in desired events, then change the data.

here is updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ckqmax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html

Or you can just use outputs and hold your buttonList in a shared folder. then when button click (output emits) change the buttonList (import in your parent component) and both component's data will change because they're holding reference to buttonList.

Comment: thankyou for your answer. but i have an requirement, i am using same child component multiple times in an page. it is working fine in first time but at 2nd time the data is not rendering.